# Make a Simple program with latin characteres (Á ,ò ,ã ) on Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows

I'm trying to make a simple program for my father to see on Father's Day. And I want All The characteres to appears right.
I have full access to the computer where I want to execute the program and I can install anything on it.
Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Obrigado Dad, por tudo que tens suportado. És bom e misericordioso\n e tem sempre força para acabares tudo, porque eu não duvido que consegues.\nAmo-te.\nDanny\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that I can't make the latin charactheres appear as it should.

Comment: Also, you need to save your source file in *UTF8*.

Comment: You need to use UNICODE for this task (ANSI characters require 1 byte per character, for a maximum of 256 different characters - unicode uses several bytes/character) So, add `#DEFINE UNICODE` _above_ where you `#include <stdio.h>`. Next, you can use wsprintf. I.e `wsprintf( L"Obrigado Dad" );` - 10/10 points for the program's purpose! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using "Raster font" on `cmd.exe`, switch to a Unicode TrueType font (eg. "Lucida Console"), and as pointed by Andrejs, save your source file in UTF8.